# sed not finding file when using a pattern through ansible

Tags: sed, centos, ansible

I have the following role:

```
---
- name: Replaces a string in a file
  command: sed 's/'"{{ target_string }}"'/'"{{ new_string }}"'/g' -i {{ target_file_name }}
           chdir="{{ target_file_location }}"
```

Which is called as follows:

```
- { role: string_replace_in_file, target_string: "localhost", new_string: "{{ myValue }}", target_file_name: "*.scripts.js", target_file_location: "/path/to/folder" }
```

The file i want to modify is aea342.scripts.js

I get the following output:

```
failed: [myMachine] => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["sed", "s/localhost/myValue/g", "-i", ".*.scripts.js"], "delta": "0:00:00.031107", "end": "2016-02-02 14:26:21.715652", "rc": 2, "start": "2016-02-02 14:26:21.684545", "warnings": ["Consider using template or lineinfile module rather than running sed"]}
stderr: sed: can't read .*.scripts.js: No such file or directory
```

When I run  `sed 's/localhost/myValue/g' -i *.scripts.js` manually on my machine however it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bruce is correct. Use `shell` to expand globs. I didn't test this. Can you try:

```
- name: Replaces a string in a file
  shell: sed -i "s/<search>/<replace>/g" target_file_location/target_file_name(s)
```

Comment: I will once i have some other things out of the way :) Will update accordingly

Comment: replaced with shell: sed "s/{{target_string}}/{{new_string}}/g" -i {{target_file_name}} chdir="{{target_file_location}}" but getting  stderr: sed: can't read .*.scripts.js: No such file or directory either way

Comment: nv mind. this might be cause of the . before the *. Confirming

Answer (score 1):

From the Ansible documentation on the [command module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/command_module.html):

> It will not be processed through the shell, so variables like $HOME and operations like "<", ">", "|", and "&" will not work

This also means that [globs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) like "*.scripts.js" won't be expanded when you use the command module.  If you need to use "*" then you should switch to using the [shell module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/shell_module.html).  As its name implies, it does run through a command shell so things like "*" will be properly expanded.

Comment: Shell will run a shell script though no? Do I have to wrap it into a shell script?

Comment: No, you don't need to wrap it in a shell script. It will basically execute the sed command just as if you typed it manually in a login shell.

Comment: replaced with shell: sed "s/{{target_string}}/{{new_string}}/g" -i {{target_file_name}} chdir="{{target_file_location}}" but getting  stderr: sed: can't read .*.scripts.js: No such file or directory either way

Comment: nv mind. this might be cause of the . before the *. Confirming